# Solving System of linear equation containing decimals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, lu-decomposition

I am working on a simultaneous linear equation problem using LU decomposition.

$5x1 + 6x2 + 2.3x3 + 6x4 = 4$

$9x1 + 2x2 + 3.5x3 + 7x4 = 5$

$3.5x1 + 6x2 + 2x3 + 3x4 = 6.7$

$1.5x1 + 2x2 + 1.5x3 + 6x4 = 7.8$

\begin{bmatrix}5&6&2.3&6\\9&2&3.5&7\\3.5&6&2&3\\1.5&2&1.5&6\end{bmatrix}

When calculating the L and U matrix I would need to perform L21 * U11 = 9. However since U11 will be 5 we will not be able to calculate L21.

$L=$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&1\end{bmatrix}

$U=$
\begin{bmatrix}5&6&2.3&6\\&&&\\&&&\\&&&\end{bmatrix}

I have tried asking my tutor to help me understand but he doesn't seem to want to do so. I am very new to this and have done some simple examples involving 2x2 and 3x3 matrices with only integer values. Would appreciate any insight on where I might be going wrong or how I would solve this simultaneous linear equation.

Comment: The numerical values are rational numbers. So, you can convert to integers. For instance, you can multiply the first, third and fourth equations by 10, and the second by 2. In any way, the approach does not depend on whether you have integer, rational or real-valued  numbers. If you have $L_{21}U_{11}=9$ with $U_{11}=5$, then $L_{21}=9/5$.

Comment: @KBA Thanks for the reply! Ah I see. Changing it to an integer is not required?

Comment: No, it is not required. You can work with real numbers.